# Undo Ctrl-w in Vim

Tags: vim, undo

I'm a pro user of vim, however, somehow I don't seem to have definitively figured out the use of time based undo, or maybe I don't really like it. 
Is there a way I can undo a deletion caused by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>
W3I will be really grateful for the help.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're referring to undoing ^W deletes made as part of an insert operation, I'm with you in wanting to know.  I guess you could remap it to something that saves the value in a script- or buffer-local variable, but I don't think there's a way to do this built into vim.  But I'm confused by your mention of time-based undo, ie `g-` and `g+`, which AFAIK is not related to the use of `i_^W`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:inoremap <C-w> <C-g>u<C-w>
```

`<C-g>u` sets undo point to the current point. And then `<C-w>` does the deletion work.

Answer (score 4):

The tip title refers to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> which is similar but not quite the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. However the same method can be used for both.

[Recover from accidental <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Recover_from_accidental_Ctrl-U)

> You can't undo these deletions. However, what you've typed is still in the `.` register. You can confirm that (after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to normal mode) with the command `:reg` which will list all registers (or just `:reg .` to display the `.` register). You may be able to copy the missing text from the register display, for example, with the mouse.
>
> Unfortunately, simply pasting the `.` register won't help because it will repeat the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> and will delete the text again. However, you can use another register (register `a` in the following):
>
> ```
> :let @a = @.
> "aP
> ```
>
> The above will paste all the text you last inserted, including what was accidentally deleted.

Comment: Would it be possible to use "setline()" and "substitute()" in a function to automate this action?